# PHP delete root node of large XML string

Tags: php, xml

We process large XML strings (over 1Gb) and want to remove the root node of them. The following code works with simplexml but blows up the ram usage of our server as it creates a whole object tree of the structure.

```
$content = '<content with="random" attributes="hello"><file>text which is over 1gb with sub nodes</file><file>another large text</file></content>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
echo $xml->children()->saveXML();
```

Is there a ram friendly way to remove the root node of a large XML string?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this, because your XML would become invalid if you try. Per Definition there must be exactly one Root-Node.

If you really want to cut away the `<content>` Tag, try it with REGEX or substring(). Maybe you should consider to save each `<file>` into a separate XML-File.

Comment: We have to combine multiple XML files, that's why we have to remove the root node. How would the regex then look like?

Comment: Try something like this: ``substr($string, strpos($string, '>'), -10);``
(-10 is the length of ``</content>``) Not tested

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Finally I came up with the solution in the my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with the following solution:

```
$xml = '<content with="random" attributes="hello"><file>text which is over 1gb with sub nodes</file><file>another large text</file></content>';
$pos = strpos($xml, '>', strpos($xml, 'content'));
if ($pos !== false)
    $xml = substr($xml, $pos + 1, - 11);
```